# Paypal not triggering OrderAfterSave

Tags: magento2, paypal, plugin

I have the following in my di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order">
    <plugin name="Module_OrderAfterSave" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderAfterSave" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

If I pay via credit card or by check/money order then my plugin works and my function gets call.

However if I pay via Paypal my afterSave function never gets called. Anyone know why?

The orders for paypal are going through fine  its just not running my plugin :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue against using the save method for *any* instance (for plugins, preferences/overrides, anything) that inherits from AbstractModel as it is deprecated because entities must not be responsible for their own persistence.

That aside, these options should work for any payment method:

### Option 1

You could create a plugin for the **place()** method in Magento\Sales\Model\Order instead:

[image: Place Method]

### Option 2

Alternatively, you could use the "after" observer:
**sales_order_place_after**

---

I will say, I'm a bit at a loss as to how you were even able to get your plugin to run seeing as Magento's core functionality (I'm looking int 2.2.1) doesn't use (or at least I can't find where it uses) **save()** to save the order (see Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement for more details: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php#L513)

But I digress...

Definitely try one of the two options (I prefer plugins over observers)