# Magento 2.2 Save Order

Tags: magento2.2

I have a custom module Name as OrderTracking and have a table order_tracking. I just want that whenever an order will place Magento will save `"Order_id"` and `"customer_id"` to my `custom table -> order_tracking`
My Custom table have these columns

1. id
2. customer_id
3. order_id
4. longitude
5. latitude

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to "listen" when Magento saves orders, I may have answered that question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213863/paypal-not-triggering-orderaftersave/213897#213897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create observer for to collect order data, You can use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event to get order details.

Create **events.xml**

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="your_observer_name" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\YourMethod" />
</event>

 </config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Observer/FileName.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;


class YourClass implements ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    // Do some stuff

}
 }
?>
```

For save data to custom table you can refer this link. [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139045/how-to-save-data-to-custom-table-using-custom-model-in-magento2)

Comment: I am new in magento and cannot understand this line that what to put in name and instance
<observer name="your_observer_name" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\YourMethod" />

Comment: public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    // Do some stuff
echo '<pre>';
print_r($order);
echo '</pre>';
echo "Order has been tracked";
}
aboce code only print {Order has been tracked}

Comment: Check here, You will get ideas about observers. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the concept of the observer. I am marking your answer **right**.